# Passing file name of a specified length in MATLAB

Tags: bash, matlab, plot

**Problem in generating file names**

I have around 4000 .txt files each containing three columns of data. I want to read all the 3 columns from a single file one at a time and then plot three values which correspond to x,y,z values on a contour plot.

These files are created at various time step. So a plot from one file will be a level curve and plots from all of them will give me a contour plot.

But the problem I want to do something which I can do in bash like this:

```
for n in `seq -f "%09g" 30001 200 830001`; do
    ./someFile$n.whateverFileFormat
 done
```

How can I do this in matlab so that if I have let's say:

```
t-000030001.txt
1 2 3
......
......
......


t-0000320001.txt
2 4 5
. . .
. . .
. . .

and so on to 

t-0008300001.txt
3 5 6
. . .
. . .
```

and on it goes.

I want to load all these files one at a time store the values in a infx3 array plot them on a contour plot and do this again and again for all the files so that I can have all of them on a single plot.

P.S. I need to reproduce something equivalent to that bash script mentioned above so as to load files appropriately then only I will be read from them

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Generating the file names or reading the files?

Comment: Generating the file names is my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to get the list of file names is this:

```
fnames = arrayfun(@(num)sprintf('t-%09g.txt', num), 30001:200:830001, 'Uniformoutput', 0);
```

Let's have a closer look: `30001:200:830001` generates an array, starting at 30001, incrementing by 200, ending at 830001. `sprintf` generates a formatted string, and `arrayfun` applies the anonymous function passed as its first argument to each element of the array in its second argument (the sequence). The output is a `cell` array containing the file names.

**EDIT**

The solution above is equivalent to the following code:

```
ind = 30001:200:830001;
fnames = cell(numel(ind), 1);
for i = 1:numel(ind)
    fnames{i} = sprintf('t-%09g.txt',ind(i));
end
```

This stores all the values in the a cell array.

Writing `@(num)sprintf('t-%09g.txt', num)` creates an [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html). The looping happens in [`arrayfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html).

Comment: @Ankit I changed your edit somewhat to reflect the original answer's structure. Note that it is usually preferable to store strings in a cell array, because that way strings of different length are handled more gracefully.

Comment: This edit is not generating a row vector of size 4000 it generates 830001 size vector even though the loop only has 4000 elements. Do you know why?

Comment: yes, fixed now. `i` was set to elements of `ind`, and since last element was 830001, that was the last index of `fnames` that was assigned to ... another reason to not do the looping explicitly ;)